# DateTime.TryParse - What was actually parsed?

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, tryparse

I'm struggling a little bit in C# with `DateTime.TryParse()`.

Essentially, given a string I need to extract the year and/or month and day in the current display culture. Sometimes I only get a year, or a month, or all three. Depending on what I get, I have a different control flow.

So far, I managed to parse a variety of strings into a `DateTime`; that isn't my problem.

My problem is that I wish to know WHAT was actually parsed (i.e. did I get a month or a year, or both).

The uninitialized `DateTime` defaults to `01/01/0001`, and I cannot set everything to an invalid date, such as `99/99/9999` and then see what was filled.

I was thinking maybe I need to do regex, but the `DateTime` class provides that parsing for multiple cultures, which is very important in this project.

I've tried searching for this, but maybe I'm not using the right terms, because surely someone else must have had this issue before.

**Update:**
Here's some sample code of what I've got:

```
string strIn = Console.ReadLine();
DateTimeStyles enStyles = DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;
bFound = DateTime.TryParse(strIn, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), enStyles, out cDT);
```

Now, bFound will be true if *something* was parsed successfully. However, I need to know *which* parts of the date were parsed successfully

Comment: Can you provide a bit more clarity ? Do you want to detect invalid dates ? actually your problem is not clear from this question.

Comment: What sorts of input are you expecting...provide some examples.  But generally, the TryParse method is simply trying to determine whether or not the string is in a format that can be made into a date.  Do you always get 4-digit years?  If not, then how would you tell the difference between a year of "12" for 1912, and December, which is the month 12?

Comment: What do you mean by "what was parsed"? It either parses completely or it doesn't. What would be an example of parsing "a month" or "a year"? Also, `DateTime` is basically just a single number. It doesn't really keep the month part or the year part in separate fields.

Comment: Ok, maybe I phrased this confusingly. I want to be able to ask "did you get a year?" or "Did you default the month because none was provided?"

Comment: Don, some examples would be "02/2012", "Feb 2012", "Feb 15 2012", "02/15/2012", "2/15/12" or "2012". Of course, in another culture the examples would be different. And then I wish to see if a year was parsed, or just a month, or an exact date.

Comment: Please provide an example string, that you would try to parse as a `DateTime` where "did you get a year" would return false. Maybe for this specific problem it would be better to save day/month/year in separate fields.

Comment: Corak, for example "March 15" in en-US would return "03/15/2013". However, in this specific case, I'd like to know in that case whether the year came from the string or was defaulted.

Comment: Okay, I don't think there is anything built in. So you need to make the checks yourself. For example if the year is anything else than 0001 or the current year, it was probably provided. If inputString.Contains("0001" or current year), it was also provided. If not, then maybe just the last two digits of the year were provided, but checking that might interfere with month/day values. Months will be especially fun. Play around a bit with [GetMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx). You might not get 100% though...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid of. That there is no built-in functionality for that. I'll play around and see how to best extract that information from the original input. I'm spoiled from the boost C++ libraries I guess :] Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont understand you but are you looking for a specified format for your datetime?

```
string dateAndTimeFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:fff"; // example of format

string dateAndTime = yourdatetimevalue;

DateTime toDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, dateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

How formats are used:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.71).aspx

EDIT 1

The tryparse returns true or false. False if it fails. Maybee that can be usefull?
Otherwise you can set the culture before the tryparse, if you are able to do so.

`DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, styles, out dateResult)`

Check the examples here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Under remarks:

"This method tries to ignore unrecognized data, if possible, and fills in missing month, day, and year information with the current date. If s contains only a date and no time, this method assumes the time is 12:00 midnight. If s includes a date component with a two-digit year, it is converted to a year in the current culture's current calendar based on the value of the Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax property. Any leading, inner, or trailing white space character in s is ignored. The date and time can be bracketed with a pair of leading and trailing NUMBER SIGN characters ('#', U+0023), and can be trailed with one or more NULL characters (U+0000)."

Hope some of that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I'm not trying to parse exactly, as the input can vary (within the bounds of what's acceptable in the current culture). However, I would like to know what components of the date were successfully parsed.

Comment: @namezero I edited the answer, hope it helps. I only think you can get true or false from a tryparse.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid of. Thank you though for providing the quote from the documentation.

Comment: @butterbox To continue my earlier comment on your deleted answer: you wanting to help is awesome. But consider providing **this** kind of help, which is really great and detailed. Keep up the good work. =)

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime.TryParse()` returns value only on success. 
So for below code example the variable dt is initialized to **`01/01/0001 00:00:00`** when declared.
When `TryParse` tries to extract date from string(*MM/DD/YYYY* format), and if it failes, then `dt` variable is having value **`01/01/0001 00:00:00`**. Otherwise `dt` will contain the actual extracted datetime value (as in 2).

1)

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse("23/15/2013", out dt);
// dt contains "01/01/0001 00:00:00"`
```

2)

```
`DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse("23/12/2013 6:25", out dt);
// dt contains "23/12/2013 06:25:00"`
```

There is no need to check WHAT was actually parsed.
Datetime value will be parsed if it's valid otherwise default datetime value will be returned.

Comment: Well, I can see the need to know. If you TryParse "Feb 03" you'll get "2013-02-03". But the year 2013 was not provided in the string. The TryParse method just "guessed" it. And OP wants to know, which values were "guessed" and which were really provided in the string.

Comment: Yes, I think the only way to do this as Corak suggested above, by probing the string for values of the parsed datetime. Or of course doing it all manually, which seems like it's not the best idea.